# Is there any way to react on Azure SQL Database changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr, azure-sql-database

I use SignalR in my application and to react on database changes I've used Sql Dependency

```
SqlDependency.Start(con);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

*Statement 'RECEIVE MSG' is not supported in this version of SQL Server*

So as I understand Azure SQL Database doesn't support Service Broker.

Is there any solution, besides migrating to Azure VM?

Example of code with SQL Dependency:

```
public class NotificationComponent
{
    public void RegisterNotification(DateTime currentTime)
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConString"].ConnectionString;
        string sqlCommand = @"SELECT [ContactID],[ContactName],[ContactNo] from [dbo].[Contacts] where [AddedOn] > @AddedOn";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddedOn", currentTime);
            if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            cmd.Notification = null;
            SqlDependency sqlDep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            sqlDep.OnChange += sqlDep_OnChange;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

            }
        }
    }

    void sqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            SqlDependency sqlDep = sender as SqlDependency;
            sqlDep.OnChange -= sqlDep_OnChange;

            var notificationHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
            notificationHub.Clients.All.notify("added");
            RegisterNotification(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    public List<Contact> GetContacts(DateTime afterDate)
    {
        using (MyPushNotificationEntities dc = new MyPushNotificationEntities())
        {
            return dc.Contacts.Where(a => a.AddedOn > afterDate).OrderByDescending(a => a.AddedOn).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Service Broker is supported in [Azure SQL Database Managed Instances](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/managed/)

Comment: What is causing the database changes to which you want to react? (Ie. can you move up the causal chain.)

Comment: Are you talking about data changes (insert / delete / update record) or schema changes?

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo about insert/delete/update

Comment: What was your final solution? I don't think a database driven approach fits with today's event driven architectures. I expect you need to set up an eventing mechanism and subscribe to the particular event.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "when an item is created" and the "when an item is modified" triggers for SQL in Azure Logic App to react to data changes.

The SQL connector in Azure Logic Apps uses a polling mechanism to query a table for changes using a TIMESTAMP / ROWVERSION column. This data type is specifically designed for this kind of processing in SQL. The polling query essentially selects all rows where the rowversion is greater than the last polled value. The behavior is reliable since the column is controlled by SQL Server and the performance is extremely fast in the case where there is no new data. When there is new data, the performance is comparable to a simple row query.

For more information, please read [this](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-triggers-in-the-sql-connector/) article.